# Perl script called from Java only takes partial string as switch

Tags: java, perl

```
String myCommand = String.format("perl script/path -id 1304444077 -description %250s -owner %s", comment, owner);
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myCommand);
```

the script is called but only takes the first string for the description switch and the rest of the description is lost.

When I run it in Unix it works fine and I get the entire description I'm looking for.

Comment: Quotes around `%-250s`?

Comment: What happens when you `System.out.println` the command and run it manually? How does the perl script process the args?

Comment: Tried it, it's not that. :(

Comment: don't use `exec(command)` but instead use `exec(cmdarray)`. In the first case a shell gets first executed so every special characters need to be protected. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html.

Comment: when i print the command it has the full description.

Comment: @michgerts Could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: +1 to @SteffenUllrich. *Very* important if any of those variables are user input -- think of what happens if someone set `description=;adduser foo` or something.

Answer (score 0):

That is a strange format string. I see no reason to left-pad all comment strings to 250 characters in a command line, and if `comment` contains whitespace then the shell will split it into words before passing the result to `perl`

The answer appears to be to enclose the format specifier in quotes, and to escape all quotes in the comment string so that they don't terminate the parameter

I've also changed the superfluous character width to a *precision*, which will limit the amount of text inserted if the value of `comment` happens to be longer than 250 characters

```
String myCommand = String.format("perl script/path -id 1304444077 -description \"%.250s\" -owner \"%s\"",
        comment.replaceAll("\"", "\\\""),
        owner.replaceAll("\"", "\\\""));

process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myCommand);
```